# Labeling layers using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, labeling

I have a point layer from an imported shapefile that I am trying to label automatically with arcpy. I had hoped that a simple:

```
def update_labels(id):
    import arcpy
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("C:\Users\username\Desktop\LOCATES.mxd")
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
    updateLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, id + '_fishnet_label', df)[0]
    sourceLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r'C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\Before you dig\\label_template3.lyr')
    arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, updateLayer, sourceLayer, False)
    arcpy.RefreshTOC()
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

would do something, but it doesn't seem to - no error but nothing happens. (template3.lyr is a point layer set up with the appropriate symbology and labels, all fields match. This example is run in IDLE with the arcpy module imported, but I have tried to run it in console with similar results)

Another suggestion was to change the data source of my template layer:

```
"label_template"
```

to a shapefile with point data:

```
"C:\\Users\\marcus.rodger\\Desktop\\Before you dig\\temp\\fishnet_label.shp"
```

using

```
arcpy.label_template.SetDataSource(mxd,r"C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\Before you dig\\temp\\fishnet_label.shp)
```

which just gives me a runtime error

I have been studying the help e.g. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/updatelayer.htm
but I'm not sure if I am just misunderstanding how it should be applied.

I am pretty new to arcpy and coding in general, the rest of the script works well but labelling features has proved harder than expected.

Comment: Are you expecting to see the labels added to an existing ArcMap session you have open?  Are you calling `mxd.save()` anywhere?

Comment: I have been trying to call the same functions in both my current session and using idle. That module is part of a larger script, I am exporting a pdf and saving the document later.  If you know of anyone who has experience labeling using arcpy, I would welcome another method. I’m not trying for anything extravagant, just turning on showlabels() and changing the font size would be enough.